# How to use/vectorize SpaCy output?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I'm performing preprocessing on a dataset that I'm planning on using as a feature set for an RF model. I don't have too much experience with NLP so just want to make sure I'm processing my text fields correctly. So far, I've:

1. Tokenized my text column
2. Filtered out stop words
3. Vectorize lemma result

I'm worried that only vectorizing the lemma result without considering the POS won't produce a meaningful result. Should I be leveraging POS in some way? Any guidance would be appreciated. Below is my function.

````
import spacy
import time

def text_analysis(df,col):
    start_time = time.time()
    results = []
    
    # Filter out stop words from text
    stop = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([f for f in x.lower().split() if f not in (stop)]))
        
    # Write lemmetization output to temp pickle file (to prevent memory issues)
    for row in nlp.pipe(df[col].astype('unicode').values, n_process=4):
        if row.has_annotation("DEP"):
            lemma_tokens = [n.lemma_ for n in row]
            lemma_desc = ' '.join([f for f in lemma_tokens])
            pos = [n.pos_ for n in row]
        else:
            lemma_desc = None
            pos = None
        
        # Vectorize lemma result
        results.append(nlp(lemma_desc).vector)
        
    print(f'{col} text processing time: {round(time.time()-start_time,2)} s')
    return results
```
````